# Missing \endcsname inserted while increasing a counter in a command

Tags: macros, counters

Given the following `WE`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}{
    sharp corners
}

\newcounter{mycounter}
\setcounter{mycounter}{0}

\newcommand{\myentry}[1]{%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{%
        \textbf{\thesection.\themycounter}~\texorpdfstring{\boldmath #1}{a}%
    }%
}

\newcommand{\mysample}[1]{\begin{mybox}
        \textbf{Sample \themycounter:} \begin{equation*}
        #1
        \end{equation*}
\end{mybox}}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    
    \tableofcontents

    \section{Samples}
    \myentry{$\symbf{a+b=c}$}
    \mysample{a+b = c}
    
    \myentry{$\symbf{x+y =z}$}
    \mysample{x + y = z}
\end{document}
```

I intend to increase `mycounter` after I read the counter. But when I do

```
\newcommand{\myentry}[1]{%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{%
        \textbf{\thesection.\refstepcounter{mycounter}\themycounter}~\texorpdfstring{\boldmath #1}{a}%
    }%
}
```

and add a `\protect` before each `\myentry{...}` call, I get the error below

```
Missing \endcsname inserted. \protect\myentry{$\symbf{a+b = c}$}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why do you want to increase the count in the toc? Given the file is typically read at the beginning or near the beginning of the document, even if this worked, you'd end up with it at 23 or whatever before you actually typeset any content?

Comment: Also any particular reason not to use `tcolorbox` to manage this? It can do this out of any suitable box.

Comment: @cfr: I need the increment because I am actually manually creating labels of my equations in ToC. Regarding, `tcolorbox`, can you explain how it can change the label in ToC?

Comment: You don't want to increment it in the ToC. You want to write the incremented value to the ToC. The code you write to the `.toc` is executed when you do `\tableofcontents`.

Comment: When you do `\tableofcontents` you get the contents of the `.toc` file written on the previous compilation. So if you have it at the beginning, say, and you have 23 lines of the kind you're trying to write, the value of your counter will be at 23 when you typeset the first box. Either you keep incrementing, so your boxes get numbered 24 to 46 or you don't, in which case they'll all be 23. Whatever you're trying to do, I'm sure that isn't it.

Comment: See e.g. sec. 4.21 of `tcolorbox`'s manual 'Counters, Labels and References'. You can create whatever label/reference scheme you need. See 5.2 for numbered boxes and lists of boxes. ToC, ToF, ToT etc. all use the same basic mechanism: they write on one run and read the file back on the next so the ToC is always one compilation behind.

Comment: Use `\newcommand{\myentry}[1]{%
    \refstepcounter{mycounter}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{%
    \textbf{\thesection.\number\value{mycounter}}~\texorpdfstring{\boldmath #1}{a}%
    }%
}` i.e. move `\refstepcounter{mycounter}` before ` \addcontentsline` and use `\number\value{mycounter}` to print the counter. The better option, though, will be to do as @cfr suggests.

Comment: @cfr: Thanks for the references.

Comment: @user299596: Thanks!